# CSS positioning situation

Tags: css, html

I have 3 divs: a banner at the top of my page (think Facebook, Twitter, or even Stackoverflow) , a search bar on that banner, and a body with the main content of the page in underneath.

I wish to position the search bar on top of the banner with the body directly below without a margin i.e. the search bar floats and the body doesn't, like so:

```
+-----------------------------+
|        +-----------+        | <-- banner with search bar within
|        +-----------+        |
+--+-----------------------+--+
   |                       |    <-- main body of page
   |                       |
   |                       |
   |                       |
   |                       |
   |                       |
   +-----------------------+
```

Comment: show your code with jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SO</title>
<style type="text/css">
div#banner {
    background: #aabbcc;
}

div#search, div#main {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

div#search {
    width: 20%;
}

div#main {
    width: 80%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner">
    <div id="search">
        Search
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    Main
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <style type="text/css">

    #banner {
      height:100px;
      position:relative;
    }

    #search-bar-container {
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }    

    #search-bar{
      height:50px;
      margin:10px auto; /*center the search bar*/
      width:200px;
    }

    #page-body {
      width:900px;
      margin:0 auto;
      min-height:500px;
    }

  </style>
  <body>
   <div id="banner">
    <div id="search-bar-container">
      <div id="search-bar">
       <input type="search" name="txt_search" />
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```